# Saving the video file from a request corrupts it

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm tryna send a video file using postman. But whenever I try to save it on the backend, it corrupts the whole file and makes it unplayable.

Here's the code,

```
if 'target_path' in request.files:
    target = request.files['target_path']
    target_path = os.path.join(app.config['TEMPLATE_FOLDER'], secure_filename(target.filename))
    target.save(target_path)
```

I did something similar for a image file and it works flawlessly like the following,

```
if 'source_path' in request.files:
        source = request.files['source_path']
        filename = secure_filename(source.filename)
        print(filename)
        source_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
        source.save(source_path)
```

But similar code doesnt weork for video, what